# Javascript closure vs regular function

Tags: javascript, closures

I was reading an expemple of javascript closure. And there is one thing I don't understand.

Here is the exemple:

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}

var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
```

Here is the full exemple: [Fidle Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/vnkuZ/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=vnkuZ)

What I understand, Is when you click on the element size-12 for ex, you will execute the anonymous function which change the size to 12.

What I don't understand, is if you change the code this way:

```
function makeSizer(size) {

    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

}
```

and call makeSizer(12) instead of size12 on click event, it doesn't work.

Ok I get this is what make closure interesting, but why my modification does not work ?

Regard,
Charles.

Comment: What "does not work" exactly mean? Show the complete "not working" example and explain what outcome you expect from it.

Comment: Because the `onclick` expects a `function`, when you use `makeSizer(12)` with your modification it will execute that function and set the `onclick` to whatever is returned, which in this case is `undefined`. Even with your change using `size12` wouldn't work.

Comment: Quentin was right my question is a duplicate and now I understand my mistake. Thanks for all your answers !

Answer (score 1):

The [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) property expects a function to be passed. In your second example that is not the case as `makeSizer(12)` is not a function, but a function call. To get it to work you would need to wrap it inside an anonymous function like:

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = function() {makeSizer(12);};
```